# Scrollbar style not applied in IE

Tags: css, wpf, internet-explorer, scrollbar, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser control that run a website... (with the IE engine)

I have some css properties to style my scrollbars :

```
scrollbar-base-color:  #333333;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #252525;
scrollbar-track-color: #252525;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #333333;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #252525;
```

When I run the application on my computer, my css is well applied :

[image]

But on another computer, the scrollbar appears like this :

[image]

The 2 computers have the last version of IE 11 installed.

Any idea why is it appearing like this ?

EDIT : the style is well applied on the second computer with Internet Explorer, but not inside my WPF application with a WebBrowser control.

Still having the problem... Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Is one computer running Windows 8.1 and the other Windows 7? Your scroll bar styling works perfectly for me on 8.1.

Comment: Yes sorry, Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 on the other one...

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.aquaScroll {
  scrollbar-base-color: aqua;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}
.bisqueScroll {
  scrollbar-base-color: bisque;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="aquaScroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div class="bisqueScroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
```

Comment: Thx, I edited my post with a screenshot,  the WPF application on the left, IE on the right